# How to make a global timer for the whole app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to make a timer that start on app load and when it finishes to alert a text and restart the app when alert is closed(when click the ok button of the alert). Have tried with a class timer but I can't send alert and reload the app. I need it to be working in the whole app, and when move to other view not restart it countdown. Is there any easy way without using CocoaPods.

```swift
import Foundation

class GlobalTokenTimer {
    static let sharedTimer: GlobalTokenTimer = {
        let timer = GlobalTokenTimer()
        return timer
    }()

    var internalTimer: Timer?
    var jobs = [() -> Void]()

    func startTimer(withInterval interval: Double, andJob job: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if internalTimer != nil {
            internalTimer?.invalidate()
        }
        jobs.append(job)
        internalTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: self, selector: #selector(doJob), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        guard internalTimer != nil else {
            print("No timer active, start the timer before you stop it.")
            return
        }
        jobs = [()->()]()
        internalTimer?.invalidate()
    }

    @objc func doJob() {
        guard jobs.count > 0 else{return}
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible adding duplicate questions. Similar question was added few hours ago [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57767575/4056108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timer is static and will work while app is alive. Implement some function that will show alert on `topViewController` of your application.

```
extension UIApplication {
    // function that lets you get topViewController of the app
    func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }

        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }

        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }

        return controller
    }

}
```

Inside your app delegate start your timer and show alert. In iOS you can't restart you app, but can set newly created `MyStartViewController` which is your home page for example and restart logic of your app.

**UPD:**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func startTimer() {
        GlobalTokenTimer.sharedTimer.startTimer(withInterval: 10) {
            let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Restart your app!", message: "Select ok!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default) { [weak self] _ in
                self?.window?.rootViewController = MyStartViewController()
                startTimer()
            })

            application.topViewController()?.present(alertVC, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        startTimer()
    }
}
```

Set your timer `repeat: false` and it would stop after finishing once.

```
internalTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: self, selector: #selector(doJob), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

**UPD:**
You do nothing in your `doJob` function, change it to this.

```
@objc func doJob() {
    guard jobs.count > 0 else { return }

    jobs.forEach { $0() }
}
```

Comment: but it is not stoping the function, and the options for this alert are not executed

Comment: @Martin which options?

Comment: @Martin why you set your timer `repeat: true` if you want it to stop after finish?

Comment: @Martin I figured out, check my update on answer. This must work, I've checked

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: but, can you make it when I restart the ,time to start again

Comment: because it now just return me and timer is not working again

Comment: I want it to restart when I go to the previuse view and works like that